# Request stream only streams on slow connections

Tags: javascript, websocket, request, stream

I've implemented request streaming for a browser app that communicates data with other non-browser services using C# WebSockets. Most of the time the sent data is of insignificant size (<5Kb). However on occasion, the requested data can be as large as 500Mb.

The system works perfectly on slower (<50mbps) connections when throttling the browser using DevTools. However I noticed that when working on an unthrottled faster connection, the data isn't sent by the WebSocket connection until after the full fetch has completed.

**Throttled Behavior**

1. Data request is submitted via async fetch.
2. Browser Network tab shows fetch in progress (Size & Time columns increment).
3. Data chunk gets sent to the WebSocket connection as it's returned by the reader.
4. Server received WebSocket message almost instantly (Minor latency in transit).
5. Steps 3-5 are repeated while reader.read() is true.

**Unrestricted Bandwidth Behavior**

1. Data request is submitted via async fetch.
2. Browser Network tab shows fetch in progress (Size & Time columns increment).
3. Data chunk gets sent to the Websocket connection as it's returned by the reader.
4. Steps 3-4 are repeated while reader.read() is true.
5. Only once reader.read() is finished does the server then start receiving the sent messages.

```js
function GetData(request){
    const response = await fetch(request);
    if (response.ok === true) {
        const reader = response.body.getReader();
        let chunkIdx = 0;

        while (true) {
            const {value, done} = await reader.read();

            if(done){
                //Process last chunk then exit reader
                SendDataChunk(value, -1);
                break;
            }
            
            SendDataChunk(value, chunkIdx);
            chunkIdx++;      
        }
    }
}

function SendDataChunk(data, chunkIdx){
    //Update UI, handle errors, etc...
    //...

    //Send the data
    this.wSocket.send(data);
}
```

I've experimented with various values for C# WebSocket servers receive buffer (8Kb up to 1Mb), but that only affects the number of frames per read message and not the receipt timing. Additionally, I've connected to the server using a non-browser client and it behaves as expected so I don't believe the anomaly is on the C# side of the equation.

That said, this is all on the dev environment with the webapp running in IIS Express so that may be adding in another variable where IIS Express just can't keep up.

Is there an error on my end, or is this just how chromium based browsers behave?